# Creating a subview in PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, addsubview

I recently went through some tutorials on how to program your own PHP MVC framework. To avoid some questions and comments: I don't want to use it in a productive environment, I just like to fiddle and get the idea of whats going on in MVC.

So far I am able to have single pages eg. http://domain/news/show/3 shows me the news-record from the database with id 3 and http://domain/news/all lists them all on one page.

Now I have multiple entities and thus multiple lists and want them all to appear on one page. Preferably the page you see when you open http://domain/

Do I have to write a new model and controller that makes calls to the other models? I'm kinda unsure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict definition or convention on this that I'm aware of.

What I would do is this:

## Class Overview

- **`Controller_Homepage`**
- **`Controller_News`**
- **`Model_NewsArticle`**

## Behavior

**Controller_Homepage**

- **`Action_Index`** fetches multiple `Model_NewsArticle` entities, has them rendered, and passes the output to view. Also fetches any other entities you may need and gives their rendered output to view.

**Controller_News**

- **`Action_List`** fetches multiple `Model_NewsArticle` entities, has them rendered, and passes the output to view.
- **`Action_View`** calls `Model_NewsArticle::factory($id)`, has it rendered, and passes the output to view.

**Model_NewsArticle**

- Contains a static **`factory`** method that accepts an `$id`. Returns an instance of `Model_NewsArticle`.
- Contains methods used to find multiple articles. A query builder would be nice here.

That's by no means comprehensive and I've left out lots of little details, but it's fairly simple and is pretty dry.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of preference really. Having another controller and model makes code separation easier in larger projects. Personally, I would only make a new controller since it is a different page with potentially different actions, and I would use the existing models to get the data to keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).